# Django 2.0 Admin: Does delete confirm even if the ForeignKey on_delete field is set to CASCADE?

Tags: django, django-2.0

Switching from Django 1.9 (I know, it's out of compliance, hence the upgrade) to 2.0. I see on_delete is a required field for all ForeignKey fields. Previously when I would delete an object from Django Admin, it would run a check and confirm if I wanted to delete records with FKs to the object I'm deleting.

Regarding the new field, if I set it to cascade (the default behavior previously), will it still confirm before deleting or do I need to use PROTECT and then do the foreign key deletes myself if I choose?

I liked being able to delete something and see what it was going to take out before actually deciding whether or not to keep the record or delete it and all cascaded records. Just want to know if I can use this technique to see what is attached to a record before I decide how to use the on_delete option.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it still confirms, just spun up a test project to double check.